# Rotate Canvas content

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've made an image editor, where i can upload an image to crop.

Now I should rotate this image but I'm not able to do this.

I've found some snippet to rotate a canvas but I can't see result, canvas doesn't rotate.

```
ctx.translate(50,50);
ctx.rotate(angle / 180 / Math.PI);
ctx.drawImage(orig_src, -16, -16);
ctx.restore();
```

I'm new in HTML/JavaScript so maybe there's something wrong in the code.

Here is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/marcom89/awb7320h/1/

Comment: You need to rewrite your code as it is full of problems. Hit F12 on your browser to get the console and it will show you the errors, and generally your code is using global scope for all the functions you are likely overwriting functionality needed for jQuery to function correctly making the whole thing untrustworthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after little fixing save/restore & clearing canvas (clearRect), also, calling "drawImage" directly inside method.

fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gLap4fsz/2/)

```
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, resize_canvas.width, resize_canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(resize_canvas.width/2,resize_canvas.height/2);
    ctx.rotate(angle / 180 / Math.PI);
    ctx.drawImage(orig_src, -resize_canvas.width/2, -resize_canvas.height/2);
    ctx.restore();
```

It's not straight probably because you're translating canvas without save/restore. Actions like translate& rotate could mess up every following operation, so remember to save/restore in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...yes now it works :-) but i saw that whe i try to resize the image, it returns at the original size and orientation...maybe i'm missing somthing else

Comment: Welll, I think your approach could be refined, as it might be unmaintainable at some stage to sync JQ object & output canvas, but anyway, it's possible with some tweaks - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xk9rahe/2/) - see for yourself :)

Comment: I've tryied with the container rotation, but in this way no loger works...maybe there's somthing else...i'm going crazy with this....

Comment: Solved...here the https://jsfiddle.net/marcom89/awb7320h/14/... Problem was that i had to rotate the image also at the resizing.

Comment: I think this line is wrong...
ctx.rotate(angle / 180 / Math.PI);
Shouldn't it be
ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
?

Answer (score 1):

### Using setTransform

To draw an image rotated, scaled, and positioned via its center

```
// ctx is the 2D context
// image is the image to render
// x,y position on the canvas to put the image center
// scale the scale of the image 1 = no scale, < 1 smaller, > 1 bigger
// angle the rotation of the image in radians with positive going clockwise
// returns undefined
function drawImage(ctx, image, x, y, scale, angle){
    ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y); // set the scale and position
    ctx.rotate(angle); // set the rotation
    ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.height / 2); // draw the image offset half its width and height
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // restore the transform to default
}
```

Comment: Solved: here the updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/marcom89/awb7320h/14/